# Is there proof that Stitch is a male?

Tags: character, lilo-and-stitch

Other than him being referred to as a 'he', I don't see how Stitch from *Lilo and Stitch* is a he.

Is there proof? I am not asking where Stitch's boy bits and girl bits are, or if Stitch has any (I think that's the appropriate way of mentioning them), I am asking for proof other than them referring to Stitch as a 'he'.

And not including Stitch's girlfriend, because the series is not canon in my serious opinion, only the movies are.

Comment: I'd ask what constitutes "proof" of Stitch's gender, if people referring to him with male pronouns doesn't count, but since this question was posted by an unregistered account that hasn't logged in since, I'm going to just VtC as "needs details or clarity".

Comment: @F1Krazy The activity of the user or them having registered their account should *in no way* matter for the (evaluation of the) quality of the question.

Comment: Shouldn't it be on _Stitch_ to define this?  If "he/him" are his pronouns then nobody should be gainsaying that.

Comment: @DavidW - The galactic overlords also repeatedly refer to Stitch as an "it", so in-universe pronouns may not be the most useful way to look at an alien that may not have the same genders as humans. In this instance, he does appear to be male, but he could just as easily have turned out to be something else.

Answer (score 13):

Stitch was created, in a lab, though genetic engineering. If his creator calls him "he", then there is no reason to question it.

Out-of-universe, Disney has always called Stitch as male in all marketing, Another authoritative source of information.

Answer (score 1):

The creators of Lilo and Stitch (Chris Sanders and Dean DeBlois) have talked about Stitch, from concept to filming, in several interviews. They are unequivocal that he was always conceived as *male*.

> **Q:** *Might Stitch have worked with a boy?*
>
> **Chris Sanders:** *Your natural inclination is to say a boy and his dog, and that's what we thought would be a good idea, this little boy in
> Kansas. But we both felt simultaneously that the soft nature of the
> story, plus the nature of Stitch's change, was going to require a
> female influence. **I think Stitch represented a male character so the
> balance would be to put him with a little girl. We wanted someone who
> was going to be in conflict with Stitch, and we realized a little boy
> might be a comrade (laughs).** The relation would be, Break that!
> Woo-hoo! This is great! We would have two characters reinforcing their
> bad behavior. It would have been fun but we wouldn't have had the
> conflict; we wouldn't have had a story. A little girl would be the
> proper character to frustrate Stitch. In that conflict, we would have
> a story about if they were going to get along.*
>
> **Dean DeBlois:** *So it became about a girl in Hawaii and there was a slow evolution of ideas...*
>
> <sub><sup>[Lilo & Stitch Revisited: Part I](https://www.awn.com/animationworld/lilo-stitch-revisited-part-i)</sup></sub>

and

> **Animated Views:** *The first idea of the film dates back to a concept drawing of Stitch Chris did in 1985. He was first intended to
> be an ugly little creature living in complete solitude in a great
> northern forest. But how was Lilo and her passion for Elvis born?*
>
> **Chris Sanders:** ***We needed a character that was going to really change Stitch and it seemed from the very beginning to both of us that
> a female character would be best to introduce him to the softer side
> of things, the more romantic side of things, and to the idea of
> family.** We created Lilo very early on. The idea that she likes Elvis’
> music came from the fact that we just wanted to make her very unique,
> initially. We also thought that, maybe, she found her mother’s
> records. She never listens to CDs in the movie; she always has vinyl
> records and a little record player that she holds around. So, that was
> the starting point for us.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Lilo & Stitch : A Little More Conversation with directors Chris Sanders & Dean De Blois!](https://animatedviews.com/2009/lilo-stitch-a-little-more-conversation-with-directors-chris-sanders-dean-de-blois/)</sup></sub>

Answer (score -1):

This question was on my mind as well. Stitch was always portrayed as male, but the confusion for me was watching the series. There were 1 or 2 episodes where Stitch is called SHE, and HER. Season 1, episode 29 'Dupe' is one such episode.

Comment: The transcript for episode 28 dupe and episode 29 short stuff show no instance where she or her is used to describe stitch. It only references Nani and Lilo. Did you mean "Lilo's back with
her little, tiny friend.

He's not tiny. He's just right."?

Answer (score -1):

Stitch is constantly referenced as a he and Angel Stitch’s Girlfriend is constantly Referred to when she is referenced to as a she

Comment: This is nowhere near being proof.